# Error installing Lua: "rm: command not found"

Tags: windows, cmd, lua, path

I am following the instructions on [this website](http://www.thijsschreijer.nl/blog/?p=863) to install Lua on my Windows 10 PC using MinGW. The problem is, when I use the `make clean` command, the following error message appears:

```
make[1]: rm: Command not found
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/temp/lua-5.3.3/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I am using Windows 10 and Lua 5.3.3, rather than Windows 7 and Lua 5.1.5, but those are the only differences that I have noticed. I have `mingw32-base`, `mingw-gcc-g++`, and `msys-base` installed as required. It looks like there is a problem with the `PATH` variable which is making the commands inaccessible.

Here is the full output when I follow the instructions up to the error (the path before all of this is shown, if that helps):

```
C:\Users\Laurence>path
PATH=C:\Python33\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\MinGW\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin

C:\Users\Laurence>SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin

C:\Users\Laurence>CD c:\temp\lua-5.3.3

c:\temp\lua-5.3.3>make clean
cd src && make clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/temp/lua-5.3.3/src'
rm -f liblua.a lua luac lapi.o lcode.o lctype.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o lbitlib.o lcorolib.o ldblib.o liolib.o lmathlib.o loslib.o lstrlib.o ltablib.o lutf8lib.o loadlib.o linit.o  lua.o luac.o
make[1]: rm: Command not found
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/temp/lua-5.3.3/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Adding `c:mingw\msys\1.0\bin` to `PATH` via the control panel did not make any difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make does not have access to the rm.exe through the path variable.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin
```

will only add that folder to PATH within your current commandline. You can run rm.exe from that command line after you have added the folder to PATH but make can't.
Once you close the command line you your changes to PATH will be lost.

Use `SETX PATH "%PATH%;c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin"` to permanently add a user variable PATH in the windows registry instead. Most likely you'll have to open a new console to make the changes available.

It is also possible to change system (LOCAL_MACHINE) variables by adding /m. Enter `SETX /?` for more options.

You could also do this through the Window GUI.
At least in your question there is a typo (missing backslash after c):

> c:mingw\msys\1.0\bin

Maybe you had one as well when you tried it through the control panel?
Make sure rm.exe is available through the path you add to PATH!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still received the same error after doing this. Is there supposed to be an `rm.exe` file in the `msys\1.0\bin\` folder? Currently I do not have such a file.

Comment: of course! make wants to run rm.exe but does not know where it is. that's why you have to add its location to PATH so Windows can find it on demand. so the problem seems to be with your mingw installation.

Comment: Thanks! I uninstalled MinGW, and reinstalled it *not using the mingw-get GUI* this time, and everything worked perfectly!